# What is the differences between LASSO and SALSA?

Tags: lasso

When I see their formulation, it is the same. 
In SALSA, the formulation is:

\begin{equation*}
\min_{x}
\phi(x) \text{ subject to } \frac{1}{2} \|Ax-y\|_F \leq \epsilon
\end{equation*}
This constrained problem is then being transformed into an unconstrained by adding the indicator function of feasible set: $x: \|Bx-y\| \leq \epsilon$ to the objective function. The resulting unconstrained problem is then transformed into a different constrained problem, by the application of a variable splitting operation. The final obtained constrained problem is then attacked by augmented Lagrangian scheme. 
$\phi(x)$ in my case is $\|x\|_1 \leq k$

The formulation for LASSO is similar:

\begin{equation*}
\min_{x} \frac{1}{N} \Sigma_{i=1}^{N}\|y_i - Ax_i\|_F^2 \text{ subject to } \|x_i\|_1 \leq k
\end{equation*}

N here is the number of cases. You can ignore it  and set it equal to 1 in my case. I'm working on a cube data, but I want to simplify the answer to 2 dimensions before applying it to 3D.

Comment: By "SALSA," do you mean the technique described at https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00287?

Comment: Hi, I mean SALSA in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4887 But I'm sure they are the same. Also, if anyone  downvote, please tell me why so I'll learn not to do it next time. This is a genuine question that I couldn't find or understand.

Comment: I suspect the downvote might have been a protest against the lack of information in your question.  Could you perhaps quote the two formulations of these procedures that you are referring to?

Comment: Please add some context for this question. I'm not sure it's answerable at present.

Comment: Hi all, I have adjusted the question. Tell me if you need any thing else. I'm not sure what is the different between the 2 approaches in solving this problem.

Comment: Yes, it is $x_i$ but you can ignore it. I just  want it to work in 2D first so setting $N = 1$